# how to use html input to subtract total value

Tags: javascript, html, cart

Please check >>>[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zAFfv?editors=101) <<<<

I cant get the *discountvalue* input field to subtract from grandtotal.

```
<input  id="discountvalue" type="number">
```

```
    function recordToFilename() {
    var input = document.getElementById('discountvalue'),
    discount12 = input.value;
```

*discount12*  does not subtract from grand total. Please check >>>[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zAFfv?editors=101) <<<<

```
document.getElementById('grandtotal').innerHTML = ": $" + (salesTotal * 0.13 + salesTotal - discount12).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use the selector element `,` on assignment:
Change is:

```
var input = document.getElementById('discountvalue'), discount12 = parseInt(input.value);
```

To:

```
var input = document.getElementById('discountvalue');
discount12 = input.value;
```

There are also two statement, line 4, 83.

Simplified:

```
function recordToFilename() {
    discount12 = parseInt(document.getElementById('discountvalue').value, 10);
};
```

Comment: Yes it was like a moment ago , I just changed it based on comment below.

Comment: it does yea what did you do :). How do I get the alert to stop coming up. Is it part of *recordToFilename* because I deleted             `alert(discount12);`

Comment: hey yea everything works fine but I cannot use jquery , anyway to write that in basic javascript? thanks

Comment: sorry I was off for a time, yes you can and would make things easier. I hope you've managed. a good start is to change the way it retrieves and changes the elements. here is a short implementation http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cfhte?editors=101 , just remembering that I had to change the codepen to use jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = parseFloat(input.value);
```

this will give you an int rather a string to use with calculations.

EDIT:

At the moment it seems like you are getting the value of the discount and trying to subtract it from grand total.

If I was you I would change this:

```
<h3 id="grandtotal"><strong>Grand Total</strong></h3>
```

to this

```
<h3 id="grandtotal">Grand Total</strong></h3>
```

and add a font-weight:bold; to your h3 class in your CSS. That way you can use the below:

```
var input = document.getElementById('discountvalue');
var grandTotal = document.getElementById('grandtotal');
var newTotal = grandTotal.value - input.value;
```

I hope I have understood.

Comment: it added it to my <[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zAFfv?editors=101)>Not sure why *discount12*  still input does not subtract total. Thanks for post

Comment: Yes I can add css classes , but that is not my problem , the input function works (as it alerts with correct value). I just need that value to subtract from *totalvalue* as inputed.